# Rotate compass in smooth way issue android

Tags: android

**This is my code which use another Sensor class and other activity but

      i want only compass to rotate in smooth way i use bitmap image on 
      canvas bitmap not rotate in smooth way**

```
  public class CompassView extends View
  {
  private int mWidth;
  private int mHeight;
  private float position = 0;
  private  Bitmap myCompassPointer;
  public CompassView(Context context) 
  {
  super(context);
  myCompassPointer=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
  R.drawable.pin_finder);
  }
  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
  {
  int cx = (mWidth - myCompassPointer.getWidth()) >> 1; 
  int cy = (mHeight - myCompassPointer.getHeight()) >> 1;
  if (position > 0) 
  {
  canvas.rotate(position, mWidth >> 1, mHeight >> 1);
  }
  //it set the bitmap to cx,cy position
  canvas.drawBitmap(myCompassPointer, cx, cy, null);
  canvas.restore();
  }
  public void updateData(float position)
  {
  this.position = position;
  invalidate();
  }
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int  
  heightMeasureSpec) 
  {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
  mWidth = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
  mHeight = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store the current rotation of the canvas in some field variable and on each update of data use the ObjectAnimator to smoothly update the value of the current rotation of the canvas to the new value. Be sure to invalidate the view on each animation frame. You can read more about animations of properties and ObjectAnimator here: [Property Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)